# Carrying out currency conversion in a CakePHP model or query

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp

I built an application in CakePHP as something of an amateur, and I have fallen into the trap of having fat controllers and skinny models. I am currently working through my code and moving much of the data manipulation into the models and generally improving my code structure.

I have hit a bit of a brick wall with currency conversion, I will try to briefly summarize how I am currently converting my currency:

I have a SQL-Server legacy database (which I am not allowed to change - the application uses the database in a read only capacity), which contains entries in a variety of currencies dictated by a "currno" field. When I summarize the data, I want it all to be in a single currency.

In a separate database (MySQL), which I have full control over, I have created a table which contains all the currency conversion rates and periodically updates.

To convert currencies in the controller, I have written a converter component which has a "convert" function like so (the column headers in the currency table are 'cur' followed by the 'currno', e.g. 'cur6'):

```
public function convert($from, $to, $amount, $table) {
        if($from == null or $to == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        for($i = 0; $i < count($table); $i++) {
            if($table[$i]['Currency']['CURRNO'] == $from) break;
        }
        $rates = $table[$i];
        $to = 'cur' . $to;
        if ($amount * $rates['Currency'][$to] != null) {
            return $amount * $rates['Currency'][$to];
        } else return 0;
    }
```

In order to reduce querying the database repeatedly, before I call the conversion function in a controller I store the currency table in a variable and pass it to the function (this seemed like a good idea to me but I could be wrong here).

After I have gathered all the data from the model I then have to convert it in the controller:

```
$contracts = $this->Territory->Contract->Ctit->getTitles($id,'territory');
$this->loadModel('Currency');
$currencytable = $this->Currency->find('all');

foreach ($contracts as &$contract) {
    if($contract['Royalty']['currno'] == $currency) {
        $contract['Title']['earned_usd'] = $contract['Title']['earned'];
        $contract['Title']['advance_usd'] = $contract['Title']['advance'];
    } else {
        $contract['Title']['earned_usd'] = $this->Converter->convert($contract['Royalty']['currno'],$currency,$contract['Title']['earned'],$currencytable);
        $contract['Title']['advance_usd'] = $this->Converter->convert($contract['Royalty']['currno'],$currency,$contract['Title']['advance'],$currencytable);
    }
}
unset($contract);
```

What I want to know is, is there a smarter way for me to do this? It feels a bit cheaty and I also (perhaps wrongly) feel like this should be something I am doing in the model. I know it is possible to use components within a model but I don't really want to replace one bad practice with another.

Apologies if this question is a bit unclear but I am finding it hard to articulate exactly what I want to know! Please let me know if there is any more information that might be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your currency conversion is in a component then you could fetch the data from your database, run the currency converted on your data to get it all in a common currency, and then pass that to your view.

Something like (pseudo-code):

```
$data = $this->ModelName->find('all');

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $row['ModelName']['amount'] = $this->Currency->convert($row['ModelName']['currency_code'], 'USD', $row['ModelName']['amount']);
}

$this->set('data', $data);
```

Of course, if you do this in multiple places then you’ll probably be looking to DRY that out. Consider creating a service class, which is a simple class that just does one thing. You could have a service class that fetches your results and converts the results’ currency:

```
<?php

App::uses('ModelName', 'Model');

class GetResultsInCurrencyService
{
    protected $currencyCode;
    protected $ModelName;

    public function __construct($currencyCode)
    {
        $this->currencyCode = $currencyCode;
        $this->ModelName = new ModelName();
    }

    public function results()
    {
        $data = $this->ModelName->find('all');

        foreach ($data as $row) {
            // Do currency conversion
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Usage in controller:

```
$service = new GetResultsInCurrencyService('USD');

$this->set('data', $service->results());
```

Comment: Thanks Martin - this is pretty close to what I'm doing right now. I guess I did something right after all!